# Why does spark-shell/pyspark gets less resources compared to spark-submit

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am running a PySpark code which runs on a single node due to code requirements.

But when I run the code using PySpark

```
pyspark --master yarn --executor-cores 1 --driver-memory 60g --executor-memory 5g --conf spark.driver.maxResultSize=4g
```

I get Segment error and the code fails, when I checked in Yarn I saw that my job was not getting resources even when they were available.

But when I use spark-submit

```
spark-submit --master yarn --executor-cores 1 --driver-memory 60g --executor-memory 5g --conf spark.driver.maxResultSize=4g code.py
```

the code gets all the resources it needs and the code runs perfectly.

Am I missing some fundamental aspect of spark or why is this happening?